# Getting Total Daily Sale for 7 days

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the date and SUM(total) for last 7 days. I am trying this code and getting **date NULL and daily_sale 0.00**

```
SELECT
  date,
  IFNULL( SUM( total ), 0 ) AS daily_sale
FROM sales
WHERE date BETWEEN NOW()
    AND DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

I am note sure how to get the date and daily total sale. I want get results as

```
date       daily_sale    
2013-01-29 500.00
2013-01-28 500.00
2013-01-27 500.00
2013-01-26 500.00
...
2013-01-23 500.00
```

Comment: and where is the sample data and desired output?

Comment: +1 , Question was li'l bit tricky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `interval - 7 day`:

```
SELECT  date, SUM(Coalese(total,0)) AS daily_sale
FROM yourtable
WHERE date BETWEEN NOW()  AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -7 DAY)
```

Not sure why `between` didn't work, check this out:

**[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9b9e/1)**

```
select dates, sum(coalesce(daily_sale,0)) as total
from sales
where dates <= NOW()
and dates >= Date_add(Now(),interval - 7 day)
group by dates
;

|                          DATES | TOTAL |
------------------------------------------
| January, 23 2013 00:00:00+0000 |   500 |
| January, 24 2013 00:00:00+0000 |   500 |
| January, 27 2013 00:00:00+0000 |  1500 |
| January, 28 2013 00:00:00+0000 |  1000 |
| January, 29 2013 00:00:00+0000 |   500 |
```

Comment: @Saleen please try with `coalesce` and `interval - 7 day` for last 7 days from `now()`

Comment: tired but same :( date is null and sale 0.00

Comment: @Saleem here I have updated with SQlfiddle demo, please take a look and comment. I have used `dates` insated of `date` given the reserved keyword.

Comment: Now it worded :D Thank you

Comment: Glad, you got it worked out. `=)` I was even experimenting to see if any date formats issue.. but really odd, still wonder why `between` didn't work :$

Comment: for months I used this date >= date_sub( now( ) , INTERVAL 12 MONTH ) and it worked. Thank you for help :D

Answer (score 0):

from MySQL [BETWEEN...AND manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

```
expr BETWEEN min AND max
```

SO change it to

```
    SELECT CURDATE( ),DATE_SUB( CURDATE() , INTERVAL 7 DAY ) AS weekEndDate, 
           `date` , SUM( COALESCE(`daily_sale`,0 ) ) AS weekly_sale
    FROM tbl_sale
    GROUP BY weekEndDate
    LIMIT 0 , 30
```

[`Working DEMO`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/40938/4)

Note:

- **date** is mysql reserve Keyword so wrap it in `` ` ``
- syntax of SUM is `SUM(column_name)` and your column name is **daily_sales**

Comment: Same date NULL and daily_sale 0.00

Comment: Tried with SELECT `date`, IFNULL(SUM(total),0) as daily_sale FROM sales WHERE date BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) but same date null and sale 0.00

Answer (score 0):

If the first date expression needs to be the lower one, as @diEcho's answer suggests, then you need to make `NOW()` the second term in the expression, not the first.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the lowest date first in BETWEEN command so NOW() have to be in the end

```
SELECT
  date,
  IFNULL( SUM( total ), 0 ) AS daily_sale
FROM sales
WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) and NOW()
```

or if you need statistic for each day:

```
SELECT
  DATE(`date`),
  IFNULL( SUM( total ), 0 ) AS daily_sale
FROM sales
WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) and NOW()
group by DATE(`date`)
```